# A Simple CRM Plugin for WordPress?

Tags: customization, plugin-recommendation

I want a simple CRM in WordPress.com, any suggestions as how to do? Which plugins to use? How to start and implement?

Comment: Please include in your question the features you think qualify as a simple CRM, and the ones that you'd get along without so proper recommendations can be made.

Answer (score 2):

Hi **@MsManiya**:

Here's what I could find for **WordPress+CRM**:

- [**SlipFire's WP-CRM**](http://slipfire.com/wp-crm/)
- [**Cregy CRM for WordPress**](http://www.cregy.co.uk/wordpress-crm/) ([also](http://www.cregy.co.uk/category/crm/))
- [**Customer Relationship Management WP Plugin**](http://cregy.wordpress.com/home/software/crm-wp-plugin/)
- [**Salesforce to Lead Plugin for WordPress**](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/salesforce-wordpress-to-lead/)
- [**WordPress integration with Tactile CRM**](http://www.paulbain.co.uk/development/wordpress-plugins/tactile-crm-plugin-for-wordpress/)
- [**CRM Tags on WordPress.org Support**](http://wordpress.org/tags/crm)

Answer (score 0):

the first one is now under google: rolopress (i can not post more than 1 link)

if you want to create your own, I think one essential thing is to link contacts with companies/households and visa versa as both custom post types, then this one comes in handy: http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/posts-to-posts/