# Can anyone recommend a wordpress based CRM/Project Management system or plugin?

Tags: plugin-recommendation

Hello I am wondering if anyone can recommend, from first hand experience, a reasonably simple CRM or project management plugin for WordPress.

I have read [this question on the topic.](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/1105/a-simple-crm-plugin-for-wordpress) But I am looking for slightly more detail and if possible someone who has actually used one of these.

The functionality I am looking for is to be able to store contacts, share files, have a forum/message board or even chat type area and some simple task/project management functions such as assigning cases to team members. One more thing, if possible users should be able to select their preferred language, preferably at least with English and Simplified Chinese, although I accept this may not be possible or may require manual translation.

I have used both sugarcrm and vtiger, but have found that them to be a bit bloated and was wondering if any of the WordPress option available would be suitable for our needs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only project I know that is viable is rolopress, download it and see what you can adjust.

FYI I have a related question open here: https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/9530/does-a-free-personal-relationship-system-exist-out-there/9545#9545 but for a PRM.

But the thing you are looking for is I think not a CRM system but a PM/software project system, all your requirements are met with RTC ( http://www.jazz.net ), free for 10 users. It has chat, users, projects, projectmanagement, tickets, version control, reports, your (agile/RUP/UP/whatever) planning and project approach etc... and all integrated. You can have rss feeds on everything and it has a REST, etc.. possibilites and an API. I have not tried version 3 yet: http://jazz.net/blog/index.php/2010/11/23/rational-team-concert-3-0-released/